# Decrypting 802.11 packets captured through wireshark

Tags: wpa2, wireshark, packet

I created my own network with security of WPA2-PSK, so I know the SSID, and password.

I then connected 2 devices (A and B) to this network and started capturing B's traffic from A using wireshark in monitor + promiscuous mode.

I hence found some packets from device B but they were all encrypted.

How do I decrypt these?

I understand I need a 256-bit key but where do I get this?

Comment: the solution of that says select channel of AP, i looked around in wireshark, couldnt understand what the AP was and where to select its channel.

Comment: Then I think you need to take this up with the Wireshark FAQ, since this is a basic software usage question and not explicitly an information security question.